# How to Log-in using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape data from this [Web](https://www.vietnamworks.com/technical-specialist-scientific-instruments-lam-viec-tai-hcm-chi-tuyen-nam-tuoi-tu-26-32-chi-nhan-cv-tieng-anh-1336108-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=2&placement=1336109&sortBy=date)

I need to login [here](https://secure.vietnamworks.com/login/vi?client_id=3).

Here is my [code](https://github.com/gialuong2801/abc/blob/main/crawl_Vietnamworks_demo).

I dont really know how to do that.
How can do this?
... 
 Sincerely thanks. <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To login you can go directly to the login [page](https://secure.vietnamworks.com/login/vi?client_id=3) and then go to the page you want to scrape.

You have to download chromedriver from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/) and specify the path on my script.

This is how you can do it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'PATH')#PUT YOUR CHROMEDRIVER PATH HERE

driver.get("https://secure.vietnamworks.com/login/vi?client_id=3") #LOGIN URL

driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("YOUR-EMAIL@gmail.com") #PUT YOUR EMAIL HERE
driver.find_element_by_id('login__password').send_keys('PASSWORD') #PUT YOUR PASSWORD HERE

driver.find_element_by_id("button-login").click()

driver.get("https://www.vietnamworks.com/technical-specialist-scientific-instruments-lam-viec-tai-hcm-chi-tuyen-nam-tuoi-tu-26-32-chi-nhan-cv-tieng-anh-1336108-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=2&placement=1336109&sortBy=date") #THE WEB PAGE YOU NEED TO SCRAPE
```

And then you can get the data from the web page.

Comment: thanks for your answer. may you help me with my new question in my profile?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need to use your main page a navigate tru that. You can just use the link `https://www.vietnamworks.com/dang-nhap?from=home-v2&type=login` and then write your credentials to the page that loads.

After the page loads, you use

```
find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="email"]""").send_keys("youremail")
password_element = find_element_by_xpath("""//[@id="login__password"]""").send_keys("yourpassword")
password_element.submit()
```

Xpath is obviously the xpath to the element you need. `.submit()` is the same as using `enter`.